# change the user_contents info in manifest.json of a chrome extension by programming

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have found this api http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS ,but this is api insert css file when the html file is loaded, and the whole page redraw cause the new css rule hide some areas of this page.Is there any idea for me to insert the css file before page rendering? I know the manifest.json can solve this problem ,but this solution is static, I can't change the style  by programming.

All I want is  that I can dynamic assign css rules(css file or css code fragment ) to some page that match my condition and doesn't blink the page. Manifest.json rules are static, and these rules do apply before DOM rendering(by using run_at option, I can gain fine grit control ).

Answer (score 0):

You should try **runt_at:"document_start"** in your manifest's content_scripts field.

[http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration)

"run at document start" injects your code before the DOM is constructed, that's why I think this will work fine.

I recommend you try this way only as a test: inject your CSS by manifest, not by programatic injection.  If you obtain the behavior you are looking for, you may tune your manifest to assure the programatic injection (.insertCSS(...)) takes place before the DOM is constructed.

Comment: Yes,I already test My CSS by manifest,and it make the page rendering smooth.when I insert CSS by programatic,some areas in the page does flash(show and hide).

Comment: I try to append this rule {"matches":"http://*/*","run_at":"document_start"} to content_scripts in manifest.json,chrome warning me that this rule needs at less "js" or "css"

Comment: Yes, the rule needs the js o css you want to insert automatically.  Programatically you have to code to tie your listeners, in order to insert your CSS before the DOM is constructed.  You can't pause the construction, you have to start your code at document start.  What event fires your code?

Comment: this event listener "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener", and my code  if(changeInfo.status == 'loading' ){
   if(tab.url.match(/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/s/) && !tabs[tabId].insert){
    //console.log("Yes this is example page");
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {'file':"css/xxx_style.css"}, function(){
     console.log("xxx_style.css inserted");
    });
    console.log("add xxx_style.css");
    tabs[tabId].insert = 1;
   }else{
    console.log("loading, url not match or css file already inserted")
   }

Comment: The code is right, it seems you can't get the event fired early enough.  If this code is complete and ilustrate your final purpose, I think you should try to insert CSS automatically, matching the url.  If you want to make more verifications on the page before inserting the CSS, I'd try injecting a content script automatically to decide & insert the CSS.

Comment: the code does work,in my CSS rules,I hide some areas in current tab page  and this code blinking the page,the page display not smoothly as normal.Anyway, thanks for your patient. Sorry for my poor Englist,I'm not a native English speaker.